# Different code in inspect element and style editor

Tags: css, firefox

I was troubleshooting an error in the layout and found my issue in the inspector

[image]

I just needed to reduce the margin.

But when I opened up the style editor to make the change, I noticed totally different code in line 315 for that style that is affected by the media query.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me.

Line 325 sets the right margin to 4%. Firefox seems to simply combine the values into one. so instead of showing:

```
margin: 0px;
margin-right: 4%;
```

it shows as

```
margin: 0 4% 0 0;
```

You can change the margin-right value to whatever you want...